# interpretability and bi-interpretability

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

The notion of interpretability (and of course bi-interpretability) as described here: [Interpretation (model theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(model_theory)), are vague to me.

I am wondering if someone can explain this notion by giving some easy examples and non-examples. Thank you!

Comment: Do you understand the wikipedia example of $(\mathbb{Q};+,\times)$ being interpreted in $(\mathbb{Z};+,\times)$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, I do. But it's still vague for me. Maybe more examples helps me to understand it better!

Comment: Chapter 1 Section 3 of Dave Marker's book Model Theory: An Introduction has lots of examples definable interpretability and interpretability.